# Cannot add DATETIME columns to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm trying to add two DATETIME columns to my User_Accounts table.

I create the columns in MySQL workbench like so: DATETIME(6)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can see how adding a `not null` column without default value would fail if the table already has data, but I would expect a different error message. Still, you could try giving it a default value. I think create time and update time can be automatically entered by MySQL. -edit- Yes, see [auto-initializing timestamps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) (It is for timestamps, not datetime).

Comment: added the full error log

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove that size specifier `(6)` from your `ALTER` statement.

```
   ALTER TABLE `Chessmates`.`User_Accounts` 
    CHANGE COLUMN `Country` `Country` TEXT(25) NOT NULL ,
    ADD COLUMN `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL AFTER `salt`,
    ADD COLUMN `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `created_at`
```

Comment: This worked, but why? MySQL workbench provides DATETIME() as a datatype, not DATETIME.

Comment: Check `MySQL` documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html for more information.

Comment: DATETIME(6) seems to of worked for me. It is only available in MySQL 5.7 and later . The number inside the brackets represents the amount of decimal places the fractional seconds can use ( microseconds ). 

DATETIME eg 2016-06-05 02:07:48
DATETIME(6) eg 2016-06-05 02:07:48.123456